# API Server and Content Server hosted on different domains, can't save cookies

Tags: django, cookies, xmlhttprequest, csrf

I have a Django server hosted on localhost:8000 and I also have my contents served by another server at localhost:80. My server has a method called get tokens which returns a csrf token and also a session token. However the browser does not save the cookie even I can see the cookies at the get request response. It just ignores it. My cors is open to localhost:80.

How do you save cookies if your api server and content servers are hosted in different places? What if I wanted to deploy my front end on a cdn and host my django backend on aws, how would i make the cookies work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the RFC for cookies (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-8.5), you can see that port is irrelevant when reading/sending cookies (using the `Cookie` header), cookies are not isolated by port. Likewise when setting a cookie (using the `Set-Cookie` header), there is no concept of specifying a port, domains do not include ports.

However, if you set your domain for some StackOverflow Cookies to .stackoverflow.com:334 (port is just an example not specific) in Chrome the cookies will not be sent, but this is most likely because this domain is now invalid.

Since the host name is the same (localhost), there are some options left, the following list may not be exhaustive.

- The Cookie is not being set at all (formatting error etc. including incorrect domain with port being specified)
- The Cookie is being set to a specific Path, which doesn't apply for the request to the other app
- The Cookie is set as SameSite strict so is not sent with the other apps request (I'm not sure if Port applies or not in this case)
- The Cookie is being set to a specific sub domain

Cookies are however isolated by domain, and there is no way to share them cross domain (from a user agent perspective). You can share cookies between two sub domains, app1.mydomain.com and app2.mydomain.com but you cannot share them between two domains, app.mydomain1.com and app.mydomain2.com.

If you need to share Cookies between domains, you must have some server side operation set the cookie for both domains separately, this is normally achieved by use of shared session data between applications.

Comment: in my case cookie domain was wrong as you have indicated, I had to specify cookie domain like this `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = "127.0.0.1"`